# Maven parent pom, set group id in external file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In my lib I need to set different groupId for different clients. Is it possible to set this property in some 'parent or base' pom file and inherit it?

The idea is to have 'parent' pom with appropriate group id in git ignore in different repos and use link to it in my project pom.

I tried to use environment variable, but get an error that group id must be a constant. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you need different groupId ? Does not make sense?

Comment: One internal test automation library is used in outsource company on several projects. Unfortunately different company names are required to be set there for different clients. And this name in supposed to be filled in group id.

Answer (score 0):

Maven shade plugin could be a solution.

Multi project layout:

- master

  - group id=neutral, artifact=my-lib

    - src/A.java
  - group id=ibm, artifact=my-lib
  - group id=google, artifact=my-lib

`ibm:my-lib` has no code and depends on `neutral:my-lib`

`google:my-lib` has no code and depends on `neutral:my-lib`

If `maven-shade-plugin` in used to build `ibm` and `google` artifact, then you finally get 3 artifacts: neutral|ibm|google:my-lib with the same content: A.class